# Ubuntu media playing become slow

Tags: sound, video, hdmi, youtube, multimedia

Recently I did a presentation. So I used Mirror option to display my desktop on the projector screen using HDMI port. After the presentation(after removing HDMI) when I tried to watch a YouTube video or play a video on SM player, the media is playing extremely slow and there is no sound coming out from the speaker, even though the volume is at maximum. All media files got affected, mp3, mp4, youtube videos etc. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

About the sound: It is routed to the HDMI sound output. (Because Ubuntu automatically assumes that of you plug in ab HDMI monitor, the sound should also go there. Good for  TVs, bad for monitors).

Solution: Open `pavucontrol`

Go to Output devices, and select the correct output device there.

[image: pavucontrol to correct your sound output]

For video, there might be multiple culprits, (including sound actually). But still
 can you show the output of `xrandr`?

It should be something like:

```
$ xrandr       
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192      
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)      
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm      
   1920x1080     60.00*+      
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)      
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```